# Auth flow with a hydrated bloc does not emit a new state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

When the user opens the app, it checks if the token exists or not from the function 'fromJson'  if exist it will return AuthAuthenticatedState
else AuthUnAuthenticatedState but in bloc listener function the state is always  AuthstartedState
please let me know what is the issue
Thanks in advance.

code:(simplified)

//—————————View———————————————

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                AuthBloc()
                  ..add(AuthStartEvent()),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
    
          onGenerateRoute: Routes.generate,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                listener: (context, AuthState state) {
                  print('state is $state');
                  if (state is AuthAuthenticated) {
                    navigateToDashboard();
                  } else {
                   navigateToLogin();
                  }
                },
                child: child);
          },
   
        ));
  }
}
//——————————————Auth bloc——

class AuthBloc extends HydratedBloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {

  AuthBloc() : super(const AuthUnknownState()) {
    on<AuthStartEvent>(_authStartEvent);
    on<AuthRequestEvent>(_authRequestEvent);

  
  }
  _authStartEvent(AuthStartEvent event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) {
     emit(AuthStartedState());
  }
  AuthRequestEvent(AuthRequestEvent event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    Var token=randomeText();
    emit(AuthAuthenticatedState(token);
}

  @override
  AuthState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>? json) {
    print('reached');//ok
    String? token = json?['accessToken'];
    //this is not triggering in listener
    return token!=null? AuthAuthenticatedState(token):AuthUnAuthenticatedState();
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(AuthState state) {
    if (state is AuthAuthenticatedState) {
      return state.toJson();
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: The AuthStartEvent event is called when the App is built, but what happens afterwards? I don't see anything being done in the _authStartEvent method inside the bloc, just the emitter changing the state to AuthStartedState. Shouldn't there be some logic here for the AuthRequestEvent event to be called? Could you explain your flow, it seems confusing.

Comment: When app is open, 'fromJson' function is called first from hydrated bloc , if I disabled _authStartEvent, in listener state is AuthUnknownState ie default state

Comment: actually I want the state return from the function fromJson in bloc Listener function